# Не загружается страница google из кода

Tags: c#

Хочу загрузить для обработки страницу поисковой выдачи google.
Загружаю программно:

```
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
            wc.Proxy = null;

            string address = @"https://www.google.com/search?q=cat&num=10&start=0";
            byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(address);
            string html = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }
```

Возникает 503 ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе по ссылке в браузере, ошибок не возникает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: HTTPS уже давно:  https://www.google.ru/search?q=cat&num=10&start=0&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=XLpAVcrPKcGXasWLgZgD

Comment: поменял на HTTPS. тоже не работает.

Comment: ваш код успешно отрабатывает, если поставить https://

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Гугл выдает `503 Service Unavailable` если он считает, что запрос выполняет не живой человек, а бот. Что в вашем случае полностью справедливо.

У гугла есть API для поиска. Если вам нужно автоматизировать поиск по определенным сайтам - посмотрите в сторону [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview).

Answer (score 0):

У меня отрабатывает нормально. Попробуйте добавить HTTP заголовки. Возьмите их с отладчика хрома.Но у меня работает и без них.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");
string html = wc.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q=cat&num=10&start=0");
Console.WriteLine(html);
}
```